# Filter (awk, set, etc.) out records from flat files

Tags: awk, sed, full-text-search, record, flat-file

I am looking to filter out specific records from a file. I thought that the easiest way would be to awk (or sed, etc.) it using the following:

```
for i in aaa bbb ccc; do awk '$i,/Record Closing String/' filename.txt >> output_file.txt; done
```

This would be in a file that had something like...

```
 aaa this is just scrap text

 There is more scrap text.
 And even more scrap text with the identifier again:  aaa.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 xaa this is just scrap text

 There is different scrap text.
 And even more scrap text with the identifier again:  xaa.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 bbb this is just scrap text

 There is more slightly different scrap text.
 And even more different scrap text with the identifier again:  bbb.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 ddd this is just scrap text

 There is different scrap text.
 And even more different scrap text with the identifier again:  ddd.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 eee this is just scrap text

 There is different scrap text.
 And even more different scrap text with the identifier again:  eee.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 ccc this is just scrap text

 There is different scrap text.
 And even more different scrap text with the identifier again:  ccc.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String
```

However, my result set is larger than my original file (it appears to contain at lest parts of the original file MANY, MANY times)... Is there  command I could run to get just one copy of my records from the first instance of the string to match to the next Record Closing String? I basically want to go from the first result match  to the next record closing string (see below)...

```
 aaa this is just scrap text

 There is more scrap text.
 And even more scrap text with the identifier again:  aaa.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 bbb this is just scrap text

 There is more slightly different scrap text.
 And even more different scrap text with the identifier again:  bbb.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String

 ccc this is just scrap text

 There is different scrap text.
 And even more different scrap text with the identifier again:  ccc.

 And even more scrap text.
 Record Closing String
```

Comment: To get this answered, you'll likely need to add more info:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'll plan generate an example later today :).

Comment: Added an example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Its still not clear to me what the output should look like.  Does it include the scrap text?  The closing record?  just the identifier?

Comment: It includes all 3. Everything from the first instance of the identifier to the next Record Closing String (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use gawk (GNU awk), then you can use regexp record separators, and this becomes very easy:

```
gawk -v RS='Record Closing String' '/aaa|bbb|ccc/' filename
```

Note that this will find the identifier anywhere throughout the record, which may or may not be what you need.  You can add a more specific regexp pattern if needed (depends on what the real data looks like).